# Find non-similar elements from 2 array list having different sizes in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, collections

I have two array lists of string type as:

List a -> [Mango, Banana, Apple]

List b -> [Man, Apple]

I have to find out non-similar elements from two lists.

Till I have implemented this:

```
List d = new ArrayList(a);
toReturn.removeAll(b);
return d;
```

But the problem with this code is that I don't want Mango as the first element from list b contains "Man" string. I only want "Banana" to be returned.

Comment: I this homework? Your instructions are bound to have some hints as to what functions are available for you to use.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you don't want Man as first string then that must mean that you need to use `contains` function, and then iterate over longer list through smaller list and print the ones which doesn't `contain` any letters.

Comment: Not a homework actually. I have came across this problem and I wanted to solve it. I can use anything.

Comment: How man and mango will be similar?, Is it because of man word present in both or char m a n present in both the list element. Please be clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over one list and find the items in it that aren't substrings of the other, and then of course to the same with the arguments reversed:

```
private static Stream<List> filterNonSimilar(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    return a.stream()
            .filter(ai -> b.stream().noneMatch(bi -> ai.contains(bi) || bi.contains(ai));
}

public static List<String> nonSimilar(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    return Stream.concat(filterNonSimilar(a, b), filterNonSimilar(b, a))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have iterate one list and then have to compare it in another, remove element if that exist in second list (viceversa), below I m sharing sample code for this approach.

```
public class Comp {

public static void main(String... strings) {

    List<String> lis1 = new ArrayList<>();
    lis1.add("applefy");
    lis1.add("boy");
    lis1.add("carrr");

    List<String> lis2 = new ArrayList<>();
    lis2.add("apple");
    lis2.add("car");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String a : lis1) {

        for (String b : lis2) {
            if (a.contains(b)) {
                result.add(a);
               }

        }

    }

    lis1.removeAll(result);

    System.out.println(lis1);

}
```

}
output : [boy]

Hope this will help.

Comment: This won't handle elements like "Man" and "Mango" that OP gave in the example.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for catching that, I really missed that part, I just update code with expected things.